# How to keep OnePlus Pad screen bright while charging?

Tags: android-13, oneplus

I am using [OnePlus Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus_Pad) as a permanent screen for monitoring/controlling smart home stuff. The power cable is constantly plugged in, and I need the screen to stay still bright.

I have the following settings:

- Developer settings:

  - Keep screen on while charging: ON
  - Do not use Lock screen: ON
- Display & brightness

  - Auto screen off: 30 minutes (the maximum available)
  - Auto brightness: OFF
  - Adaptive Sleep: OFF

The problem is that the screen gets **dimmed** after the time in the "Auto screen off" setting.

How do I make it constantly bright?